# Can an HTTPs page be reused for searching?

Tags: language-agnostic

I have a main page that users visit via https. From that page, they can do a google search. However, the search results is displayed via http and I no longer have control over the search page. Is there a way to 'trap' the results and send it over a custom https page so the users results can be private?

Update: I guess the real question is can they browse the web through my website and since my site is https, get a private browsing session via my website.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Google AJAX Search API to integrate search results in your own page:
http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/

Comment: Thanks. Please see update. This won;t help if they click on a search link.

Comment: @Russ well then what you are describing is an HTTPS proxy.

Comment: Thx Earlz - I guess I was just trying to do something the hard way.

Comment: Perhaps you can make an ajax request to your server with the url you want to navigate to, obtain the HTML of that url from the remote server, embed that HTML code in your page dynamically, and intercept the link clicks in this HTML to repeat this process again (but be aware that this ugly workaround won't work with all the pages)